# Not able to call mysql store procedure using php mysqli prepare statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a SP names UserRegister which I am calling using php mysqli. Somehow it is not getting called(I am not getting any data back)
Below is my code

```
$username = 'user1';
$password = 'password';
$deviceId = 'device_1';
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'MyUser', 'MyPassword', 'MyDatabase');
$call = $mysqli->prepare('CALL RegisterUser(?, ?, ?, @userToken, @status, @message)');
if (!$call)
{
    echo 'Prepare failed';
}
$call->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $deviceId);
$call->execute();
$select = $mysqli->query('SELECT @userToken, @status, @message');
$result = $select->fetch_assoc();
echo $result['@userToken'];
//No result from above echo

//Did this to check if select works otherwise
$select = $mysqli->query('SELECT username from user');
$result = $select->fetch_assoc();
echo $result['username'];
//above echo display result correctly
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong with SP call using mysqli.
Executing SP from mysql workbench works fine.

Comment: Problem was that user did not had execute permission for database.

Comment: Oh, in that case you can delete the question, or post that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that user did not had execute permission for database.